# Connecting to mongodb on azure virtual machine (linux)

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, azure

I edited    `*mongod.conf*` : commented    `*bindIp:127.0.0.1*` line, activated 
   `*mongod.service*`, and many other stackoverflow advises

I want to connect to    `*mongodb*` server using my    `*nodejs*` application and    `*robomongo*`

This is my nodejs code:

```
*mongoose.connect('mongodb://--------:27017/loginapp', { useMongoClient: true }, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    }
});*
```

[image: **commented <code>bindIp</code>**]
   [image: **activated mongod.service**]
[image: **can't connect with robo mongo**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not comment bindip, instead add the ip's to allow connection from remote like.
Use accordingly to your requirement.

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.161.100 ( for specific ip's)

bindIp: 0.0.0.0 ( for all ip )
```

And then restart mongo

sudo service mongod restart

Comment: when i try your answer:    

 mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-12-12 12:25:54 UTC; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 9022 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 9022 (code=exited, status=2)

Comment: i have modified answer, can you try now, and show the exact mongod.conf settings after changing

Comment: again same this answer, when i comment this line #bindIp: 0.0.0.0/0
mongod.service : activated but i cant connect robomongo

Comment: dont need "/" : bindIp:0.0.0.0  is correct
thank you :)